# Error when I try to reverse rows in matrix on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matrix

I create a matrix 7x29. Now I need to invert it. In this case, I need invert the rows.
Here is the matrix:

`matrix[7][29]`

and I try to use this:

```
matrix_invert = matrix[::-1,:]
```

but the following error appears:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

If you know what happens here, please answer me, thanks!

Comment: Is this a list of lists? In that case you can not use a comma: since the concept of a "2d lists" does not exists in (vanilla) Python, numpy has however 2d lists.

Comment: I like how your matrix is female.

Comment: yep, I have 7 lines for 29 numbers
I want the first one to go to the last one.

Comment: @LucasDiehl: that is not the question... Please provide a *sample expression* that generated the list.

Comment: thaks bro, I got it! I just exclued the second part

Comment: It work now
Thanks for open my mind

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not really "*inverting*" a matrix, since inverting a matrix means that if you multiply the inverted matrix with the matrix, then you retrieve the *identity* matrix.

What you here aim to do is probably swapping "reverse" the rows of the matrix. Here you seem to represent your matrix as a list of lists. With the sublist representing the "rows" of the matrix.

You can then slice the outer list with:

```
# shallow copy
reversedmatrix =  matrix[::-1]
```

indeed, here we construct a list where the elements are reversed, since these elements - the sublists - are the rows, we thus constructed a new list containing the "old" sublists in reverse order. For example:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,4], [2,5]]
>>> reversedmatrix = matrix[::-1]
>>> reversedmatrix
[[2, 5], [1, 4]]
```

Note however that here we do *not* make a deep copy of the matrix: if you change a row (for example the first one) in the original matrix, then that change will be reflected in the corresponding (for example last) row of the reversed matrix. For example:

```
>>> matrix[0][0] = 14
>>> reversedmatrix
[[2, 5], [14, 4]]
```

We can, for such two dimensional nested list, make a *deep* copy with:

```
# non-shallow copy
reversedmatrix =  [list(row) for row in reversed(matrix)]
```

For example:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,4], [2,5]]
>>> reversedmatrix =  [list(row) for row in reversed(matrix)]
>>> matrix[0][0] = 14
>>> reversedmatrix
[[2, 5], [1, 4]]
```

This is however not a "really deep" copy, since if the elements of the rows are not immutable, then again updates of the state of these objects will be visible through both the original `matrix`, and the `reversedmatrix`. You might thus want to make a deep copy with [**`copy.deepcopy`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) like:

```
# deep copy
from copy import deepcopy

reversedmatrix =  [deepcopy(row) for row in reversed(matrix)]
```